# jQuery.ajax method get data without refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, methods

I have this problem, i like to do is that no refresh.
what i want is that when i search then press enter, the playlist should not refresh.

the web sample of my page is http://cocopop12.site11.com/v1.7/index.php

is my jquery script correct? do i need to use ajax so that the page will not refresh?

```
$(function(){
$('input[name="searchsubmit"]').click(function(e) {         
    e.preventDefault();
    var qS = $('#qsearch').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"",
        data: qS,
        dataype: 'html',
        success: function(data){
           $('input#qsearch').html(data);
            return false;
        }
    })
}); 
});
```

the button is

```
<div class="search">
<form id="quick-search" action="" method="get">
<p>
<label for="qsearch">Search:</label>
<input class="tbox" id="qsearch" type="text" name="q" value="Keywords" title="Start typing and hit ENTER" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Keywords';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Keywords') this.value='';" />
<input class="btn" alt="Search" type="image" name="searchsubmit" title="Search" src="./css/search.gif" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

thanks for the time.

Comment: Have you tried `return false;`

Answer (score 3):

try `success` instead of `done()`, you cannot pass the ajax call `data` to `done()` method:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"",
        data: qS,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function(data){
           $('input#qsearch').html(data);
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert('done')
    })
```

Comment: Use `,` after `dataType:'html'` also a typo

Comment: yes i added please see the website :-) the link is http://cocopop12.site11.com/v1.7/index.php --still the same but the box was 'done' it said

Comment: Try adding `return false`, after your ajax function.

Comment: @user1506189 sorry, there were some typos in the code, it should work now.

Comment: @user1506189 yes, just change the `dataype` to `datatype`

Comment: it still refresh :( why is that

Comment: Suggestion just change your `name="searchsubmit"`  to `id="searchsubmit" ` ... also your click event `$('#searchsubmit').click(function(e)`

Comment: its still refresh :-( please see the updated of my website http://cocopop12.site11.com/v1.7/index.php when i use firebug it said no errors